# Changing reference text style

Tags: color

I'm trying to change the style of the text of the images reference. I want something like you see in textbooks, for example with the words

> (fig. 1.23)

in bold, colored and maybe a different font. So I define a new color

```
\definecolor{viola}{rgb}{0.42,0.05,0.09}
```

and try this:

```
(\textcolor{viola}{\textbf{\textsf{\textbf{fig. \ref{cap1:tree}}}}}).
```

But what I'm getting is this:
[image]

How can I change the numbers style as well?

Comment: *Only* references to figures, not references to tables or citations or sectional units?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a perfect case for the [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) package- otherwise you're faced with typing that formatting every time you wish to reference a figure (yikes!).

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE to play with- see the [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) documentation for further details.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}      
\usepackage{cleveref}     

\definecolor{viola}{rgb}{0.42,0.05,0.09}
\crefformat{figure}{\protect\textcolor{viola}{\bfseries\textsf{fig.~#2#1#3}}}
\Crefformat{figure}{\protect\textcolor{viola}{\bfseries\textsf{Fig.~#2#1#3}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \rule{20pt}{20pt}
  \caption{My figure}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Use \cref{fig:myfig} mid sentence.
  \item \Cref{fig:myfig} is appropriate for the beginning of a sentence.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, it works without errors, i ran Latex 2 times but I keep gettin
**fig ??**
and the warning "reference ____ undefined" :(

Comment: Ok, now it works BUT the numbers are still in black. I think the problem is that I have hyperref with the colorlinks set to true and the linkcolor = black (otherwise table of contents is all colored in red...).
Anyway I can "override" hyperref only for the images links?

Comment: Anything? Please.... :(

Comment: @nico I would try [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)