# Cleveref set text color of label and counter globally

Tags: pdftex, color, cleveref

I'm using `hyperref` and `cleveref` in my document. Now, for clarity to my readers I want the links (that will reference other documents so might not be clear) to have a different color than black. And, for my own sanity, I would prefer to just keep using the `\cref{...}` command. How would I achieve this? I can find [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127884/changing-reference-text-style) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401047/change-link-color-of-eqref) (along more), however; the first is not globally, and only works for that specific type. The second redefines the `\cref{}` command, which shouldn't be the solution to this basic problem.

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: Colored chapter]

This can be created using the following:

```latex
\textcolor{bluegray}{\cref{chap:lorem}}
```

However, when I try to get the `\textcolor` command to be used globally I can only come this far:

[image: Not colored chapter]

This can be created using the following in the preamble:

```latex
\crefdefaultlabelformat{\textcolor{bluegray}{#2#1}#3}
```

And just using `\cref{chap:lorem}` in the text. With this solution, chapter is not colored bluegray as well, which is what I want to achieve. This is logical, because this command only applies to the label counter as per the [`cleveref`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) docs.

The solution mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127884/changing-reference-text-style) does what I want using `\crefformat{<type>}{<format>}`; however, the code there only works for that specific type. I don't want to go around and having to re-define this for every type I use in my document (though certainly possible, I feel like there has to be a cleaner way for this). I don't see a `\crefdefaultformat{<format>}` command or the alikes in the [`cleveref`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) docs.

What would be the best approach? Am I basically forced to override the default `\cref{}` command?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\crefname` command to change the text "chapter" to whatever you want, including colored versions:

```
\crefname{chapter}{\textcolor{bluegray}{chapter}}{\textcolor{bluegray}{chapters}}
```

Use `\Crefname` with analogous syntax for the `\Cref` version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's another possible solution; however, I would have to redefine all the types that I want to use. This is of course less than ideal again, since this would cause a lot of code duplication :-)

Comment: You could probably redefine `\crefname` and `\Crefname` themselves to include the `\textcolor`, though this would still require you to include `\crefname{chapter}{chapter}{chapters}` etc for each counter cleveref recognizes by default. I'll update the answer if I think of a better way.

Comment: For now I have simply defined two new commands; `\ccref` (colored cref) and `\Ccref`; which fits my needs. Simply just added this `\newcommand{\ccref}[1]{\textcolor{bluegray}{\cref{#1}}}` to the preamble, and use it like the regular `\cref` command. Feel free to add this to your answer; then I'll mark it as the solution :)

Comment: I think that's sufficiently different from my solution that you should post it as a separate answer (and then feel free to mark it as accepted).

Answer (score 2):

Because I didn't want to redefine the original command, I simply settled with adding a new command as follows:

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\definecolor{bluegray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}
\newcommand{\ccref}[1]{\textcolor{bluegray}{\cref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Ccref}[1]{\textcolor{bluegray}{\Cref{#1}}}
```